# Ruby regex for last 3 characters of a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string: `$29.99`. I want to remove the decimal point `.` and surround the fractional-part `99` with a `<sup>` tag: `$29<sup>99</sup>`.

The format can change, though; the decimal point can be a comma instead of a dot: `,99`.

Bonus: Separately, a regex to extract the currency label, taking into account that it can be of variable length (R$, $, Rs, etc...).

Comment: What regex have you tried so far?

Comment: Try http://rubular.com/, it's great. :)

Comment: I'm trying, but I can't figure out how to get the last 3 characters.

Comment: `/(\$|\342\202\254)(\d+)[\.,](\d+)/` should give you the currency, e.g. $ or €, the numbers before . or , and the numbers after . or ,. You can use those to construct a new string representation.

Comment: @alfa thanks, although that does not take into account the length of the currency label. It matches `R` only if you tried `R$`.

Comment: You don't really want the regex for the last 3 characters of a string. The title is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = '$29.99'
result = str.gsub(/\.(\d+)$/, '<sup>\1<sup>')
```

Comment: -1 Not in Ruby as the OP requests.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell Missed that, added the ruby version.

Comment: Awesome! Replaced downvote with upvote.

Comment: Just delete the PHP part.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.9.3p385 :012 > "$29.99".gsub(/(\.|,)/,'<sup>').concat("</sup>")
 => "$29<sup>99</sup>"
```

and extract the currency:

```
1.9.3p385 :020 > ("USD>as$29.99" =~ /(.*?)\d.*/ ; $1)
 => "USD>as$"
```

Answer (score 1):

This handles all the non-bonus-points scenarios:

```
1.9.3p392 :009 > "$29.99".gsub(/(\d+)[,.](\d+)/, "\\1<sup>\\2</sup>")
 => "$29<sup>99</sup>"
1.9.3p392 :010 > "$29,99".gsub(/(\d+)[,.](\d+)/, "\\1<sup>\\2</sup>")
 => "$29<sup>99</sup>"
1.9.3p392 :011 > "R$29,99".gsub(/(\d+)[,.](\d+)/, "\\1<sup>\\2</sup>")
 => "R$29<sup>99</sup>"
```